# Pyside2 QTextBrowser overwriteMode does not replace old text

Tags: python, qt, pyside2, qtextbrowser

I'm using the PySide2 package and found that the `overwriteMode` won't work in my code. Here is what I wrote:

```
self.ui.textBrowser.setOverwriteMode(True)
self.ui.textBrowser.insertPlainText('test1\ntest2\ntest3')
self.ui.textBrowser.moveCursor(QTextCursor.Start)
self.ui.textBrowser.insertPlainText('hhh')
```

[Complete source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDJrJ.png)

I used Qt-Creator to design my GUI and my settings for the QTextBrowser looks like that:

[QTextBrowser settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwWeu.png)

I got the following output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y84F4.png)

As you can see, the first line should be 'hhht1' but it gives 'hhhtest1'.

I'm testing this with PySide2 version 5.11.2 on a Windows 10.

I am new to Qt and can anyone please help me out? What am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: Please take the time to read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#overwriteMode-prop) of the `overwriteMode` property:

> This property holds whether text entered by the user will overwrite existing text
>
> As with many text editors, the text editor widget can be configured to insert or overwrite existing text with new text entered by the user.

So apparently the `overwriteMode` affects only text entered **by the user**.

You probably need to do something like:

```py
text = 'test1\ntest2\ntest3'
self.ui.textBrowser.setPlainText(text)
inserted_text = 'hhh'
text = inserted_text + text[len(inserted_text):]
self.ui.textBrowser.setPlainText(text)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes sense.

Comment: Please also have a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).